# How to create structure (or command) by which I make 2 parallel texts and 2 lines for some side remarks along with a curly line across the whole page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, paragraphs

How to create structure (or command) in LaTeX by which I make 2 parallel texts and 2 lines for some side remarks along with a curly line across the whole page? Schematically, it would look like this (of course, it needs to be symmetric which is hard to draw on a picture):

[image]

I need this for the translation of some old manuscripts but I should also add my text (that is loremipsum on my drawing). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `tabularx` package.  It looks like you want ragged right formatting with no indention to paragraphs.  Here was my attempt at what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.1\linewidth}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}

\begin{document}

The main text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\vspace{3ex}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}S|R|R|S@{}}
Side text 1 side text 1
&
Parallel text 1 parallel text 1 parallel text 1 parallel text 1 parallel text 1 parallel text 1
&
Parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2 parallel text 2
&
Side text 2 side text 2 side text 2 side text 2
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1ex}
$\underbrace{\hspace{\linewidth}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's great, however, I have one problem. When the text goes to the next page it does not automatically break the page. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure.  You could try using the xltabular package, and then \begin{xltablar}

Comment: @PhEx What text goes to the next page? The parallel text 1 or the parallel text 2? Or the side text? Maybe it needs to be more exact.